# How much do I have to write?

Tags: code-golf, counting

Writing out numbers is among the Hello worlds of programming, often the numbers 1-10.

I want to write out many numbers! Many, Many numbers. But how many numbers do I have to write?

## Task

Given an integer input, give a number as output that would give me the number of digits that would be in a string containing all integer numbers in the range from 0 to the input, inclusive. The negation identifier ("-") counts as a single character.

## Example I/Os

Input: 8
Written out: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
Output: 9

Input: 101
written out: 0,1,2,3....,99,100,101
Output: 196

Input: 102
written out: 0,1,2,3....,100,101,102
output: 199

Input -10
Written out: 0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10
output: 22

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). The lowest number of bytes wins!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

Code:

```
ÝJg
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394rlf6//@GBoYA)

Explanation:

```
Ý     # Range [0 .. input]
 J    # Join into one string
  g   # Get the length of the string
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>55</s> 46 bytes

```python
lambda n:len(`range(abs(n)+1)`)+2*~n+3*n*(n<0)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HcsxDsIwDEDRGU5hdbKTgOJ2QRHchKGuSFCl1qA0WwVXDy3Lf9NPt3udZB4eAhqmqNhn0WdEGRZUskw92dZ81XZGDerVU02vDCUuBUYFvDhgz3taByf2FI6Hdx61QLP60H0CrLzRnLdrloL76CD9Jar1Bw)**

Getting better.

Answer (score 11):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 23 bytes

```
f x{[#([seq(0,x)]&"")]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#@5@mUFEdrawRXZxaqGGgU6EZq6akpBlb@z83MTNPoZqLM9pCR8HQwBBEGOko6BoaxCrUKKQpxAPJgqLMvBKFeK7a/wA)

Explained:

```
f x{[#([seq(0,x)]&"")]}
f x{                  } /* Defines function f with parameter x. */
        seq(0,x)        /* Creates a stream of numbers from 0 to x. */
       [        ]       /* Creates an array. */
                 &""    /* Joins with "". */
     #(             )   /* Calculates the length of the resulting string. */
    [                ]  /* Returns the value. */
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:len(`n`)+(n and f(n+cmp(0,n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FYxNCoAgGAXXdYq3kT7JQGsTQZ1Fy4SgXiHdv5/NzGrmSeMejjkGcNhXiqfXtRCBEUlYL8cl1lBr/aQzg9iI3sBZ96M1aJwdyuLKG29UqotoJnyqoCA0/@NLXw)

Comment: +1: You really cannot beat this intelligently made recursive solution with Python

Answer (score 7):

## Bash + OS X (BSD) utilities, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

*Thanks to @seshoumara for saving 2 bytes.*

```bash
seq 0 $1|fold -1|wc -l
```

Test runs on Mac OS X:

```bash
$ for n in 8 101 102 -10 -1 0 1; do printf %6d $n; ./digitcount $n; done
     8       9
   101     196
   102     199
   -10      22
    -1       3
     0       1
     1       2
```

---

Here's a GNU version:

## Bash + coreutils, <s>40</s> 38 bytes

*Again, 2 bytes saved thanks to @seshoumara.*

```bash
(seq $1 0;seq 0 $1)|uniq|fold -1|wc -l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@69RnFqooGKoYGANYhgAmZo1pXmZhTVp@TkpCrqGNeXJCro5////NzQwAgA)

Comment: @tuskiomi I wrote coreutils when I meant BSD utilities -- I tested it in Mac OS X, where it does work on negative inputs too (seq there isn't the same as GNU seq).

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Nice GNU solution. Go ahead and post it yourself if you'd like to; I think it's too different to count as a variant of mine.

Comment: Ok, [here you are](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112597/11259) :)

Comment: How about using `fold -1|wc -l` to do the counting? It is shorter.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2,  <s>83</s> ,<s>78</s> 64 bytes

shortest version:

```
lambda x:sum(map(len,map(str,(range(0,x+cmp(x,.5),cmp(x,.5))))))
```

this version saved 5 bytes, thanks to @numbermaniac :

```
x=input()
print len(''.join(map(str,(range(x+1)if x>0 else range(0,x-1,-1)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@V9hm5lXUFqioclVUJSZV6KQk5qnoa6ul5WfmaeRm1igUVxSpKNRlJiXnqpRoW2omZmmUGFnoJCaU5yqABE10KnQNdTRNdQEgf//dQ0NAA)

this one I came up with on my own after that (same amount of bytes):

```
x=input()
print sum(map(len,map(str,(range(x+1)if x>0 else range(0,x-1,-1)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@V9hm5lXUFqioclVUJSZV6JQXJqrkZtYoJGTmqcDootLinQ0ihLz0lM1KrQNNTPTFCrsDBRSc4pTFSCiBjoVuoY6uoaaIPD/v66hAQA)

Comment: You can use `map` on the second line for 78 bytes: `print len(''.join(map(str,(range(x+1)if x>0 else range(0,x-1,-1)))))`. You _might_ save even more by making it a lambda.

Comment: @numbermaniac can I do something similar this way?

Comment: @numbermaniac here is an equivalent: `print sum(map(len,map(str,(range(x+1)if x>0 else range(0,x-1,-1)))))`

Comment: `lambda x:sum(map(len,map(str,(range(x+1)if x>0 else range(0,x-1,-1)))))` for 71 bytes

Answer (score 6):

## Java 7, 74 bytes <sub>*(recursive - including second default parameter)*</sub>

```
int c(int r,int n){r+=(n+"").length();return n>0?c(r,n-1):n<0?c(r,n+1):r;}
```

**Explanation (1):**

```
int c(int r, int n){     // Recursive method with two integer parameters and integer return-type
                         // Parameter `r` is the previous result of this recursive method (starting at 0)
  r += (n+"").length();  //  Append the result with the current number's width
  return n > 0 ?         //  If the input is positive
     c(r, n-1)           //   Continue recursive method with n-1
    : n < 0 ?            //  Else if the input is negative
     c(r, n+1)           //   Continue recursive method with n+1
    ?                    //  Else (input is zero)
     r;                  //   Return the result
}                        // End of method
```

---

## Java 7, <s>81</s> 79 bytes <sub>*(loop - single parameter)*</sub>

If having a default second parameter as `0` for this recursive approach isn't allowed for some reason, a for-loop like this could be used instead:

```
int d(int n){String r="x";for(int i=n;i!=0;i+=n<0?1:-1)r+=i;return r.length();}
```

**Explanation (2)**

```
int d(int n){                 // Method with integer parameter and integer return-type
  String r = "x";             //  Initial String (with length 1 so we won't have to +1 in the end)
  for(int i=n; i != 0;        //  Loop as long as the current number isn't 0
      i += n < 0 ? 1 : 1)     //   After every iteration of the loop: go to next number
    r += i;                   //   Append String with current number
                              //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return r.length();          //  Return the length of the String
}                             // End of method
```

---

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/AsY34d)

```
class M{
  static int c(int r,int n){r+=(n+"").length();return n>0?c(r,n-1):n<0?c(r,n+1):r;}

  static int d(int n){String r="x";for(int i=n;i!=0;i+=n<0?1:-1)r+=i;return r.length();}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(0, 8) + "\t" + d(8));
    System.out.println(c(0, 101) + "\t" + d(101));
    System.out.println(c(0, 102) + "\t" + d(102));
    System.out.println(c(0, -10) + "\t" + d(-10));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
9   9
196 196
199 199
22  22
```

Comment: I like this solution, :)

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)!

```
StringLength[""<>ToString/@Range[0,#,Sign@#]]&
```

Anonymous function, taking the number as an argument.

#### Shorter solution by [Greg Martin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56178/greg-martin), 39 bytes

```
1-#~Min~0+Tr@IntegerLength@Range@Abs@#&
```

Comment: You can use `Sign@#` for `#/Abs@#`.

Comment: You can save a few bytes with a slightly different approach: `1-#~Min~0+Tr@IntegerLength@Range@Abs@#&`. The initial `1` accounts for the digit of 0, while `-#~Min~0` accounts for all the negative signs if the input is negative.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>20 26</s>  29 bytes

```ruby
->x{[*x..-1,0,*1..x]*''=~/$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@59mq2tXUR2tVaGnp2uoY6CjZainVxGrpa5uW6evol/LxVWgkBZtaGAUC2boGhpAGAax//8DAA)

Comment: Why the increase?

Comment: The first version did not work for negative numbers, the second version had a problem with zero as input.

Answer (score 4):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 5 bytes

```
n0R.L
```

### Explination

```
n0R   # A Stack of all numbers between 0 and the input converted to a number.
   .L # The length of the stringification of this.
```

Simple solution, works like a charm.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn-2#@59nEKTn8///f11DAwA)

Answer (score 4):

#### PHP, <s>59</s> 60 bytes

**Outgolfed by Roberto06 - https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112536/38505**

Thanks to [roberto06](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64847/roberto06) for noticing the previous version didn't work for negative numbers.

Simply builds an array of the numbers, puts it to a string, then counts the digits (and minus sign)

```
<?=preg_match_all("/\-|\d/",implode(",",range(0,$argv[1])));
```

Run example: `php -f 112504.php 8`

- [8 test case](https://eval.in/752102)
- [101 test case](https://eval.in/752103)
- [102 test case](https://eval.in/752104)
- [-10 test case](https://eval.in/752100)

Comment: This doesn't work for a negative input, [see here](https://eval.in/752056)

Comment: You could save 3 bytes using `join` instead of `implode` because it is an alias.

Comment: there is no need to escape the minus -1 Byte. On the other hand you can change your regex to `[--9]`

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```hs
f 0=1
f n=length$show=<<[0..n]++[n..0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mYGBryJWmkGebk5qXXpKhUpyRX25rYxNtoKeXF6utHZ2np2cQ@z83MTNPwVahoCgzr0RBRSFNQ9fQQPM/AA) Edit: saved 1 byte thanks to @xnor!

**Explanation:**

In Haskell for numbers `a` and `b` `[a..b]` is the range from `a` to `b` in 1-increments or 1-decrements, depending on whether `b` is larger `a`. So for a positive `n` the first list in `[0..n]++[n..0]` is `[0,1,2,...,n]` and the second one is empty. For negative `n` the second range yields `[0,-1,-2,...,n]` and the first one is empty. However if `n=0` both ranges yield the list `[0]`, so the concatenation `[0,0]` would lead to a false result of `2`. That's why `0` is handled as a special case.

The `=<<`-operator on a list is the same as `concatMap`, so each number is converted into a string by `show` and all those strings are concatenated in one long string of which the `length` is finally returned.

---

Before xnor's tip I used `[0,signum n..n]` instead of `[0..n]++[n..0]`.
 `signum n` is `-1` for negative numbers, `0` for zero and `1` for positive numbers and a range of the form `[a,b..c]` builds the list of numbers from `a` to `c` with increment `b`. Thereby `[0,signum n..n]` builds the range `[0,1,2,...,n]` for positive `n` and `[0,-1,-2,...,n]` for negative `n`. For `n=0` it would build the infinite list `[0,0,0,...]` so we need to handle `0` as a special case, too.

Comment: I think `[0..n]++[n..0]` should do for `[0,signum n..n]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
⟦ṡᵐcl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9o/rKHOxc@3DohOef//3hDg/9RAA)

Builds the range [0,input], converts each number to string, concatenates into a single string and returns the length of the result

Comment: I noticed TIO has an argument `Z`; what's up with that? Should it be in the count?

Comment: @steenbergh: Leo's submission is a function, not a full program. Giving the argument `Z` to the Brachylog interpreter tells it to add an appropriate wrapper to make the function testable. (If you ran it as a full program, it wouldn't produce any output.) We allow either program or function submissions here, so that shouldn't count against the byte count, as it's not actually part of the submission.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>41</s> 35 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to user59178*

Since [ʰᵈ's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/112504/how-much-do-i-have-to-write/112526#112526) was wrong for a negative input, I took it upon myself to build a new solution :

```
<?=strlen(join(range(0,$argv[1])));
```

This function :

- Builds an array from `0` to `$argv[1]` (aka the input)
- Implodes it with an empty character (i.e. transforms it to a string)
- Echoes the length of the string

[Try it here!](https://eval.in/752325)

Comment: This is a nicer solution to mine, idk why I thought I had to do that `preg_match()` :(

Comment: Well, I wouldn't have thought of `range()` if it wasn't for your solution, I guess we're even ;)

Comment: you can save 3 bytes by using `join()` instead of `implode()`. it's an alias for the same thing. http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php

Comment: And 3 more by omitting the 'glue' parameter.

Comment: I knew there was an alias for `implode`, but I didn't know I could omit the gue parameter. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>26</s> 20 bytes

`sum(nchar(0:scan()))`

Very basic approach:

- Make a vector 0:x
- Count the characters in each value (will be coerced to a string automatically)
- Sum

<s>Not sure if there are any tricks to cut down the function definition?</s>
6 bytes saved thanks to Giuseppe, by taking input from stdin instead.

Comment: you could do `sum(nchar(0:scan()))` instead and read `n` from stdin instead.

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, 52 bytes

```
t=0;for i=0,io.read()do t=t+#tostring(i)end;print(t)
```

Iterates through a for loop from 0 - input, converts the integer `i` to a string and adds the length of the string to `t` before printing `t`

Answer (score 3):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 25 bytes

```
:[0,a,sgn(a)|A=A+!b$]?_lA
```

Explanation:

```
:[0,a     Read 'a' from the cmd line, start a FOR loop from 0 to 'a'
,sgn(a)|  with incrementer set to -1 for negative ranges and 1 for positive ones
A=A+!b$   Add a string cast of each iteration (var 'b') to A$
]         NEXT
?_lA      Print the length of A$
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
0hSZ}&:VXzn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@2@QERxVq2YVFlGV9/@/oYEhAA)

```
0h           % Implicitly input n. Append a 0: gives array [n 0]
  S          % Sort
   Z}        % Split array: pushes 0, n or n, 0 according to the previous sorting
     &:      % Binary range: from 0 to n or from n to 0
       V     % Convert to string. Inserts spaces between numbers
        Xz   % Remove spaces
          n  % Length of string. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 110 bytes

```
@set/a"n=%1,t=n>>31,n*=t|1,t=1-t*n,i=0
@for /l %%i in (0,1,9)do @set/a"t+=(i-n)*(i-n>>31),i=i*10+9
@echo %t%
```

Computes `sum(min(0,abs(n)+1-10^k),k=0..9)+(n<0?1-n:1)`. (I only have to go up to `9` because of the limitations of Batch's integer arithmetic.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
def f(i,j=1):
 if i==0:print j
 else:j+=len(`i`);f((i-1,i+1)[i<0],j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JcXBCoAgDADQu1@x44YKrlNYfkkEHnIwEYnq/43oXd44ioCgupqYogEV0JRCPC/tD1QDpd0lVpta6Zg10yKI6tmpZdp0DburNARnMoIc@G/68hzIjBc)

Longer than but different from other Python solutions. Defines a recursive function called as e.g. `f(10)`

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 23 bytes

```powershell
-join(0.."$args")|% Le*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@blZ@Zp2Ggp6ekkliUXqykWaOq4JOq9f//f0MDIwA) (will barf on TIO for very large (absolute) inputs)

Uses the `..` range operator to construct a range from `0` to the input `$args` (cast as a string to convert from the input array). That's `-join`ed together into a string (e.g., `01234`) and then the `Le`ngth is taken thereof. That is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Comment: The exact solution I had in my head when I read this question 

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 18 bytes

```perl6
{chars [~] 0...$_}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25sqtVFBLzk9JVbD9X52ckVhUrBBdF6tgoKenpxJf@z8tv0hBRcvTT688vyilWC83sUBDW0tToZpLQaE4sVIBrFElnqv2v4WCoYEhEBsp6BoaAAA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  chars        # how many characters (digits + '-')
    [~]        # reduce using string concatenation operator &infix:<~>
      0 ... $_ # deductive sequence from 0 to the input
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 50 bytes

*Collaborated with @ETHproductions*

```
n=>{for(t="";n;n<0?n++:n--)t+=n;alert(++t.length)}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + GNU coreutils, 28

```bash
eval printf %s {0..$1}|wc -c
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#DcNNCoAgEAbQfaf4FrYcmWkVdJrwB4QYQ6UW1dnNBy/mAkVSrBCWcQEJj2DIBp8nDDU0EMFoD9d@4CxJW8Rc8bC1Rr73diDXfdbQfw).

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 28 bytes

```
\d+
$*
1
$`1¶
1+
$.&
^-?
0
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/gfk6LNpaLFZcilkmB4aBuXIZCnp8YVp2vPZcCl9/@/BZehgSEQG3HpGhoAAA)

#### Explanation

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert the number to unary, keeping the sign untouched.

```
1
$`1¶
```

Each 1 is replaced by everything up to itself plus a newline. With this we get a range from 1 to n if n was positive, from -1 to n with an additional `-` at the start if it was negative. All numbers are in unary and separed by newlines.

```
1+
$.&
```

Convert each sequence of ones to the corresponding decimal number.

```
^-?
0
```

Put a `0` at the start, replacing the extra `-` if it's there.

```
.
```

Count the number of (non-newline) characters.

Answer (score 3):

## Emacs, 20 bytes

```
C-x ( C-x C-k TAB C-x ) M-{input} C-x e C-x h M-=
```

The command itself is 20 keystrokes, but I need clarification on how this should be counted as bytes. I reasoned that counting each keystroke as 1 byte would be the most fair. The command above is written conventionally for easier reading.

### Explanation

```
C-x (
```

Begin defining a keyboard macro.

```
C-x C-k TAB
```

Create a new macro counter. Writes `0` to the buffer; the counter's value is now 1.

```
C-x )
```

End keyboard macro definition.

```
M-{input} C-x e
```

After hitting META, type in your input number. The `C-x e` then executes the macro that many times.

```
C-x h
```

Set mark to beginning of buffer (which selects all of the text thus generated).

```
M-=
```

Run character count on the selected region. The number of characters will be printed in the minibuffer.

### Example

Apologies for the terrible highlighting color. This is an example of using this command with the input 100. The output is in the minibuffer at the bottom of the screen.

[image: Example execution with input of 100]

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure one keystroke is one byte.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere There are two thoughts I had about that: 1) Can Ctrl+character be represented as a single byte? And 2) I see a lot of answers here counting Unicode chars as one byte, but they are not, so I thought maybe CodeGolf maybe has its own definition of "byte"? Thanks.

Comment: I really don't know. But you can ask on [Meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @cheryllium Some languages use a SBCS that fits a different set of 256 characters in 1 byte than ASCII. You can only count it as 1 byte if there are less than 256 characters to choose from in that language.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 32 bytes

31 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
$\+=y///c for$_>0?0..$_:$_..0}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1bULy0u0k/KzNMvSC3KUdAt@K8So21bqa@vn6yQll@kEm9nYG@gp6cSb6USr6dnUFv9/7@hgREA)

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>77</s> 73 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen*

Lambda function:

```
(r)=>{var l="";for(int i=0,s=r<0?-1:1;i!=r+s;i+=s)l+=i;return l.Length;};
```

Ungolfed and with test cases:

```
class P
{
    delegate int numbers(int e);
    static void Main()
    {
        numbers n = (r) =>
        {
            var l = ""; 
            for (int i = 0, s = r < 0 ? -1 : 1; i != r + s; i += s)
                l += i; 
            return l.Length;
        };
        System.Console.WriteLine(n(8));
        System.Console.WriteLine(n(101));
        System.Console.WriteLine(n(102));
        System.Console.WriteLine(n(-10));
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change the `while` to `for` to save a couple of bytes: `(r)=>{var l="";for(int i=0,s=r<0?-1:1;i!=r+s;i+=s)l+=i;return l.Length;};` (**73 bytes**)

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen You are right, thanks.

Comment: You can probably use an int counter and add the length inside the loop to save some bytes. If you compile to a `Func<int, int>` you can call the functions like `r=>...` to save 2 bytes (can probably do this anyway).

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 44 bytes

```js
f=(n,i=1)=>n<0?f(-n)-n:n<i?1:n+1-i+f(n,i*10)
```

```html
<input type=number oninput=o.textContent=f(+this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 2):

### REXX, 56 bytes

```
arg n
l=0
do i=0 to n by sign(n)
  l=l+length(i)
  end
say l
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
r0Ṿ€FL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@19k8HDnvkdNa9x8/v//r2toAAA)

Jelly's surprisingly bad at this, mostly because it doesn't have a dedicated builtin for stringifying integers; it does have a builtin for stringifying *anything*, but that means we can't have it autovectorize over lists.

### Explanation

```
r0Ṿ€FL
r0      All numbers from {the input} to 0, inclusive
   €    For each of those numbers numbers:
  Ṿ       Find its string representation
    F   Concatenate the resulting strings
     L  Take the length of the resulting string
```

Comment: The `L`ength builtin doesn't work directly on integers? Preposterous!

Comment: Wait, can you use `D` instead of `Ṿ€`?

Comment: @ETHproductions: No, it doesn't deal with negative numbers correctly.

Comment: Ah, got it. And I guess there's no 0-byte way to add 1 to every number if the input is negative :P

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n?(n+"").length+f(n>0?n-1:n+1):1
```

Port of my Python answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#LcVBCoAgEAXQq4SrGUxxWoWgHkYcW8h3Ufc3iN7mLU1IGYVgjWE/GvpzWSXkUOAkwgpHWXXinqP5MTspnbxvShLk//h2EpjXCw)

Comment: It's not *only* Node.js though, it should work on any platform that supports ES6.

Comment: Yeah, I just used the auto-generated TIO answer.

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't notice there was an option to do that :-)

Comment: Yep, either with the mouse or by pressing **Esc**, **S**, **G**.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
ò ¬l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@394k8KhNTn//xsaGAEA)

#### Explanation:

```
ò ¬l
ò     // Creates a range from [0...Input]
  ¬   // Joins the array into a string
   l  // Returns the length
```

Answer (score 2):

## SQL (PostgreSQL), 76 bytes

```sql
SELECT sum(length(a::text))FROM generate_series(least(0,$1),greatest(0,$1))a
```

This is an [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html).

Comment: SQL! That's a rare one

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 211 bytes

```
interface n{static void main(String[]a){int n=Integer.parseInt(a[0]),k=1,i;a[0]="";if(n<0)k=-1;for(i=0;i!=n+k;i+=k){a[0]+=i;if(i!=n)a[0]+=',';}System.out.print(a[0]);System.exit(a[0].replace(",","").length());}}
```

Takes number as first command line argument. Returns output as an error code:

```
Input: -10

0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10
Process finished with exit code 22
```

Ungolfed version with comments:

```
interface n {
    static void main(String[]a) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(a[0]),                 // Input number 
        k = 1,                                          // For loop increment
        i;                                              // For loop counter
        a[0] = "";                                      // Empty string
        if(n < 0) k = -1;                               // If input number is negative loop increment is negative
        for(i=0; i != n + k; i += k) {                  // For loop
            a[0] += i;                                  // Append number to string
            if (i != n)                                 // If not the last number
                a[0] += ',';                            // Append comma
        }
        System.out.print(a[0]);                         // Output string
        System.exit(a[0].replace(",","").length());     // Return length of string without commas as error code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### K, 29 Bytes

I have a feeling there is a better way...

```
f:{#,/$((+;-)x<0).(0;!1+abs x)}

(+;-)x<0     ---> Call this A. If x is less that 0, return - otherwise return +
(0;!1+abs x) ---> Call this B. A list; (0;the numbers from 1 to the absolute value of x)
A.B          ---> Apply A to B, e.g1. (-).(0;0 1 2) ==> 0 -1 -2 e.g2 (+).(0;0 1 2) ==> 0 1 2
,/$x         ---> $tring x (x is numbers asc or desc) and flatten the list ,/
#x           ---> Finally count the flattened list
```

Some tests...

```
  f 8
9
  f 10
12
  f 101
196
  f 102
199
  f -10
22
  f -100
293
```

Comment: `{$[x<0;a;0]+#,/$!1+a:abs x}` for **27** bytes. Sums up string of 0..abs[input], if input was negative then add the abs[input] as this is the number of `-` you'd need to print the string.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 48 bytes

```clj
(count(apply str(range(min 0 %)(max 1(inc %)))))
```

---

```clj
(defn how-much-to-write? [n]
  ; Count the characters in the resulting string
  (count
    ; Basically "joins" the list with ""
    (apply str
      ; Creates an ascending/descending range, depending on the value of n
      (range (min 0 n) (max 1 (inc n))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 25 bytes

```
:sign\0\abs|>*''join size
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#DcZBCsIwEAXQq3xRmERcJK5EsCcZKJEMGolp6NSNtmePWTx45gLvfHfG6J3Fb1faVdOjsONw13U4Er2mVKDpK62AsT9hwztUPKccEZNWzJIlqIDYsFnRsSVEySDD0YJAB4/b0DNLzaifpf0B)

### Explanation

```
:sign\0\abs|>*''join size    stack: (n)
:                            stack: (n n)
 sign                        stack: (n sign[n])
     \                       stack: (sign[n] n)
      0                      stack: (sign[n] n 0)
       \                     stack: (sign[n] 0 n)
        abs                  stack: (sign[n] 0 abs[n])
           |>                stack: (sign[n] range[0, abs[n]])
             *               negates the range if negative
              ''join         said range as a single string
                     size    the desired length
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scala 75 Bytes

```
(x:Int)=>{
  val? =Math.abs _
  (0 to?(x))./:("")((a,c)=>a+","+c* ?(x)/x).size-1
}
```

I'm not sure how I can improve it any further. The `Math.abs` is really really annoying. I think there is probably a better way to go about doing the negative stuff.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
0ṡṅL
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiMOG5oeG5hUwiLCIiLCI4XG4xMDFcbjEwMlxuLTEwIl0=)

Explanation:

```
0ṡ    # Range from 0 to n
  ṅ   # Join by nothing
   L  # Get the length of that
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended),  <s>9</s>  6 bytes

```apl
⍴∊⍕¨…⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94P@j3i2POroe9U49tOJRw7JHfVNBwv8VwKCAy4ILxjI0MERiG8HZh9YbGgAA)

*-3 thanks to @Adám*

##### Explanation

```
⍴∊⍕¨…⎕
    …⎕  ⍝ Get the range from 0 to the input
  ⍕¨    ⍝ Convert each to string
 ∊      ⍝ Flatten the list into a single string
⍴       ⍝ And get the length of the string
```

Old 9-byter:

```
{⍴∊⍕¨0…⍵}
{       }  ⍝ Create a function:
     0…⍵   ⍝  Get the range from 0 to its argument
   ⍕¨      ⍝  Convert each to string
  ∊        ⍝  Flatten the list into a single string
 ⍴         ⍝  And get the length of the string
```

Comment: [6](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94P@j3i2POroe9U49tOJRw7JHfVNBwv8VwKCAy4ILxjI0MERiG8HZh9YbGgAA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám nice! Can you just check my explanation?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, although I'd describe `∊` and `⍕¨` as two different steps. `⍕¨` converts each number into a string and `∊` flattens.

Comment: Thanks, updated.

Comment: Is this your first APL answer?

Comment: @Adám yes it is

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
Đ±⁺0⇹?ŕ⇹:ŕ;ŘǰąŁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRDGx817jJ41L7T/uhUIGl1dKr10RnHNxxpPdr4/7@uoQEA)

```
Đ                   implicit input; Đuplicate
 ±                  get sign
  ⁺                 increment
   0                push 0
    ⇹               swap top two items
     ?              if top of stack is truthy:
      ŕ⇹            ŕemove top of stack; swap top two items
        :ŕ          otherwise: ŕemove top of stack
          ;         either way:
           Ř        Řangify
            ǰ       ǰoin with no delimiters
             ą      convert to ąrray of characters
              Ł     get Łength; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 65 bytes

`T=n=>{m=n>0?1:-1,o="";for(i=0;i!=n+m;i=i+m){o+=i}return o.length}`

Comment: You can save a few bytes like this. https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#LcVBCoAgEADAr0QnpQy3UyRrn/AHYSXoLlidor5uEM1lXIWF0F4JyeoJRgUtY12bhbMISE0yQWEy3GCQJvvjzKQe7qKn9djuMjPtHH0XeRVODLKtnAAN//23Ai1leQE

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 72 bytes

```
let f={i in(min(i,0)...max(0,i)).reduce(0){$0+"\($1)".characters.count}}
```

The "characters.count" really kills the score.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
-(.+)
$*-¶$1
.+$
$*
\d|$
$%` 
(1*) 
$.1
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@roaetyaWipXtom4ohl562CpDNFZNSA6RVExS4NAy1NBW4VPSAUv//6xoaAAA)

**Explanation**

```
-(.+)
$*-¶$1
```

If the number is a negative, let's say **-n** (i.e. there is a `-` in the input), then replace the input with **n** `-`s, and **n** on the next line. In the end we just want to count the characters, and for **-n** as input, there will be exactly **n** `-` signs in the range.

```
.+$
$*
```

Convert the number at the end of string into unary.

```
\d|$
$%`
```

Replace any digit character or the end of the string with all the text before it on the same line, plus a space. For a sequence of `1`s, this results in  `1 11 111 ...` up until the original sequence. This builds the range from 0 to **n**, in unary.

```
(1*) 
$.1
```

Conversion back to decimal. Any series of `1`s followed by a space is replaced with the number of `1`s.

```
.
```

Count the matches of `.` and output it. `.` matches any single character except linefeed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
#J:^0\,a|a,1
```

Takes input from command-line argument. Verify all test cases at [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#c1NIVIi2sDY0MARiI2tdQ4NYLoWA/8peVnEGMTqJNYk6hv///wdKAQA)

#### Explanation

Some weird tricks in this one:

`0\,a` is the inclusive range from `0` to `a`.

If `a` is negative, we want to take the inclusive range from `a` to `0` instead. A naive approach would be a ternary expression with `a<0`, but we can do better. The problem is that something like `(0,-11)` is a perfectly valid Range object and is truthy, even though the range it represents contains no numbers<sup>1</sup>. We want to convert it to an empty list (falsey).

To achieve this, we apply unary `^` to split the Range into characters. This operator works itemwise, so for example giving it `0\,10` would result in the list `[[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [1 0]]`. Splitting into characters won't make a difference to the result, since we're going to join everything together anyway. But crucially, it forces the conversion of the Range into a List. So an input of `-10` now results in the empty list `[]`.

Now since `[]` is falsey, we can take the logical Or of the above with `a,1` (i.e. `range(a,1)`, not including the upper bound) and get the elements we want.

Next, we need to join them together. Unfortunately, Join has a higher precedence than Or, so we would need parentheses. But another approach is to modify Join with the compute-and-assign meta-operator `:` (which is like the `=` in `+=` in C-like languages, but more flexible). This lowers the precedence of the operator such that parentheses aren't needed. Assigning to an rvalue is a warning, but not an error.

Finally, we take the length (`#`) of the resulting string, which is then autoprinted.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Such "backwards" ranges are used in string slicing, where the negative number means "the index 11 characters from the end."</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## C++ 102 Bytes

```
int f(int n){int o=0;std::string s;for(n=n<0?o=-n:n;n>=0;)s+=std::to_string(n--);return s.length()+o;}
```

Ungolfed

```
int f(int n)
{
    int o=0;
    std::string s;
    for(n=n<0?o=-n:n;n>=0;)
        s+=std::to_string(n--);
    return s.length()+o;
}
```

Will add explanations.

Comment: Suggest `int o=n<0?(n=-n):0;std::string s;for(;n>=0;)` instead of `int o=0;std::string s;for(n=n<0?o=-n:n;n>=0;)`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
ljk}0
```

Uses ais523's Jelly algorithm, *except* that the range starts from 0.

Thanks to [RK.](/users/44670) for -1.

Comment: You could get rid of the `M` by just doing `ljk}0`

Comment: @RK. And I *knew* there *is* a shorter way than `s\`M`!

Comment: that's the feeling, right?

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 15 bytes

```
ri_g\z),f*:`:+,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vygzPj2mSlMnTcsqwUpb5/9/XUMDAA)

Explanation:

```
ri_g\z),f*:`:+, e# Accepts an integer from STDIN.
ri              e# Get integer from STDIN.
  _g\           e# Store the integer's sign behind it.
     z)         e# Take the absolute value and increment it, to make an
                e# implicit range.
       ,        e# Create range [0..N].
        f*      e# Multiply every integer in the range with the sign we
                e# stored earlier, so as to include the - signs.
          :`    e# Map repr.
            :+  e# Concatenate.
              , e# Length.
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>38</strike> 35 bytes

```
<?=strlen(join(range(0,$argv[1]))); // 35 bytes
<?=strlen(join("",range(0,$argv[1]))); // 38 bytes
```

Useage: `php file.php 8`

The join is a little used alias of `implode()`, and php can easily join numbers together as a string. [Titus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55735/titus) commented that the glue isn't needed in `join()` if you want a empty string.

Comment: Save three bytes: The glue parameter for `join` is optional (see codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86340/55735 and http://php.net/implode).

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 80 bytes

Golfed:

```java
n->{String r="";for(int i=0;i<=(n<0?-n:n);++i)r+=i;return r.length()-(n<0?n:0);}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
public class HowMuchDoIHaveToWrite {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (final int[] test : new int[][] { { 8, 9 }, { 101, 196 }, { 102, 199 }, { -10, 22 } }) {
      final int input = test[0];
      final int expected = test[1];
      final int actual = q(n -> {
        String r = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= (n < 0 ? -n : n); ++i) {
          r += i;
        }
        return r.length() - (n < 0 ? n : 0);
      } , input);
      System.out.println("Input:    " + input);
      System.out.println("Expected: " + expected);
      System.out.println("Actual:   " + actual);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  private static int q(java.util.function.IntFunction<Integer> f, final int input) {
    return f.apply(input);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 20 bytes

```
(#":i.1+|p)-(p+|p)%2
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! By default, all answers to code golf challenges must be full programs or functions. Taking input from predefined varibales is not allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I was unaware, I'll correct it as soon as I figure out a compact valid method.

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 146 Bytes

This is a complete `program` requiring a processor supporting Extended Pascal, ISO standard 10206, features.
The number `20` may need to be adjusted but is sufficient for `maxInt` = 2<sup>63</sup> − 1.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var s:string(20);i,n:integer;begin n:=0;read(i);for i in[i..0,0..i]do begin writeStr(s,i:1);n:=n+length(s)end;write(n)end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program howMuchDoIHaveToWrite(input, output);
var
    temporaryPrint: string(20);
    i, totalLength: integer;
begin
    totalLength := 0;
    read(i);
    
    { The `[i..0, 0..i]` denotes a `set` constructor literal.
      This eliminates the issue of taking account `0` twice.
      The ranges `i..0` and `0..i` are (inside a set constructor)
      shorthand for all integral values within the intervals. }
    for i in [i..0, 0..i] do
    begin
        { The `:1` specifies the _minimum_ width.
          If omitted, a processor-defined default
          will be assumed. This could be, e. g. 20. }
        writeStr(temporaryPrint, i:1);
        totalLength := totalLength + length(temporaryPrint)
    end;
    
    write(totalLength)
end.
```

**135 Bytes**:
Since `n`, the `totalLength` variable, is an `integer`, it is limited to values in the range `−maxInt..maxInt`, thus `n := n + length(s)` will never (without an error) exceed `maxInt`.
We can *deduplicate* this information by using `string(maxInt)` as the `temporaryPrint` variable data type.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var s:string(maxInt);i:integer;begin s:='';read(i);for i in[i..0,0..i]do writeStr(s,s,i:1);write(length(s))end.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 40 bytes

```
=SUM(LEN(SEQUENCE(ABS(A1))*-1^(A1<0)))+1
```

Input in cell `A1`.

Answer (score 0):

### C#, <s>59</s> 76 bytes

```
n=>string.Concat(System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(n>0?0:n,(n<0?-n:n)+1)).Length;
```

Longer than I wanted it to be because of the minus and `Range` takes a start and a count not start and end.

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 33 bytes

```
~.abs),\.{.abs/}0if:S;{S*`,}%{+}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#@1@nl5hUrKkTo1cNYujXGmSmWQVbVwdrJejUqlZr12r9/69raAAA)

Explanation:

```
~.abs),\.{.abs/}0if:S;{S*`,}%{+}* # Evals STDIN.
~                                 # Eval.
 .abs),\                          # Store an absolute value inclusive range behind the original integer.
        .{.abs/}0if:S;            # Store the integer's sign in S.
                      {S*`,}%     # After applying the input's sign, get the length of the string representation of every integer in the range.
                             {+}* # Sum.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 63 bytes

```
lambda n:sum(map(len,map(str,range(*[[0,n-1,-1],[n+1]][n>0]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), 44 bytes

#### xxd-style hexdump:

```
00000000: 2653 4da0 6280 40a0 7852 a043 ccd0 80cc  &SM b.@ xR CÌÐ.Ì
00000010: a043 8b23 0020 8001 8b53 a062 4da0 4382   C.#. ...S bM C.
00000020: 53d0 80a0 1f20 8048 2043 253a            SÐ. . .H C%:
```

#### Equivalent JavaScript (adapted from [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112554/42091)) (45 bytes):

```
(f=_=>A?(A+"").length+f(A-=Math.sign(A)):1)()
```

#### Explanation

Declares a recursive IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) `f`, using pre-initialized variable `A` with numeric input to count down and incrementally calculate the amount of characters in the range of numbers.

#### [Try the demo here](https://patrickroberts.github.io/bean/#h=JlNNoGKAQKB4UqBDzNCAzKBDiyMAIIABi1OgYk2gQ4JT0ICgHyCASCBDJTo=&i=MTAx&f=0&w=1)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `JL`, 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ė
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faFm0kpePUuyCpaUlaboWi45MW1KclFwM5S5YbGhgCGECAA)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ĖJl
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS45M88pZUpyUXAwVWLDY0MAQwgQA)

##### Explanation

```python
     # Implicit input
Ė    # Push [0..input]
 J   # Join into string
  l  # Push length
     # Implicit output
```